# Switch between windows with frames

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have main window with frames and a popup where I do some operations:

```
within_frame("MainFrame") do
  find("btnNewItem").click #opens popup window
end

within_window(windows.last) do
   within_frame("frmFrame2"){
      some_operations
      find("btnOK").click #closes a popup
     }
end

within_window(switch_to_window(windows.first)) do
  within_frame("MainFrame") do
     find("btnDeleteItem").click #deletes item
     accept_popup_dialog
  end
end
```

But when operations are done in popup window and it was closed, I get an error that:

```
Failure/Error: within_frame("frmFrame2"){
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError:
       Window is closed
```

What I do wrong?

I use Capybara 2.4.4

Comment: assure that there is no other frame wrapping your frmFrame2... if so you would have to call frmFrame2 within your frmFrame1 for example... And finally assure that the frame you are dealing with is really under windows.last...

Comment: Problem is that, all operations in `within_frame("frmFrame2")` execute well and window closes. And then it somehow returns back to  `within_frame("frmFrame2")`. There is only 1 frame in Windows IE popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is occurring in the `within_frame` method when trying to switch back to the parent frame.

It seems like a bug, so th best thing to do would be to raise it as an issue in the [Capybara project](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues).

In the meantime, the quickest solution would be to rescue/ignore the exception:

```
within_frame("MainFrame") do
  find("btnNewItem").click #opens popup window
end

within_window(windows.last) do
  within_frame("frmFrame2"){
    some_operations
    find("btnOK").click #closes a popup
  } rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError # Add a rescue here
end

within_window(switch_to_window(windows.first)) do
  within_frame("MainFrame") do
    find("btnDeleteItem").click #deletes item
    accept_popup_dialog
  end
end
```